# Does maven-archetype-quickstart support fxml ? If yes, How should I enable it?

Tags: maven, javafx, fxmlloader, archetypes

I am working on geotools project.  Showing error (Exception in Application start method) while loading FXML file. There is no Location issue, I have double-checked my FXML file's location. The same code is working in other projects. Please help me, how to integrate FXML into the maven-archetype-quickstart project.

Answer (score 0):

> Does maven-archetype-quickstart support fxml ?

No.

Instead, see [openjfx.io getting started doc for JavaFX maven projects](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven), or (my favorite) use the Idea [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) if that is your IDE.

Additionally, there are [Maven archetypes for JavaFX](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-archetypes) unrelated to the QuickStart archetype.  I don’t necessarily recommend them.  Instructions for their use can be found in the readme  of the linked repository.